# What structure pcap_t have?

Tags: winpcap

Where the definition of `pcap_t`? I just found `typedef struct pcap pcap_t;` in `pcap.h` but `pcap` havn't definition there and wincap manual have same problem without description of this or may be i didn't find right. If this on library then may be someone can tell possible structure?

Comment: pcap_t is to be treated as an opaque handle. You are not supposed to access any of its members. Once created, you only pass it to other pcap functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible answer ([here's the source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-9/libpcap/pcap-int.h)):

```
struct pcap {
    int fd;
    int snapshot;
    int linktype;
    int tzoff;      /* timezone offset */
    int offset;     /* offset for proper alignment */

    struct pcap_sf sf;
    struct pcap_md md;

    /*
     * Read buffer.
     */
    int bufsize;
    u_char *buffer;
    u_char *bp;
    int cc;

    /*
     * Place holder for pcap_next().
     */
    u_char *pkt;


    /*
     * Placeholder for filter code if bpf not in kernel.
     */
    struct bpf_program fcode;

    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that wincap have source).

Comment: Please be aware that if you ever write any code that depends on the layout of a pcap_t, there is ***ABSOLUTELY NO GUARANTEE*** that your code will continue to work with a future version of WinPcap - or that it'll work with libpcap.  As nos indicated in his comment, it's an opaque structure, and is intended to be so; in libpcap, for example, it has changed quite significantly with the past few releases, and those changes will probably be part of WinPcap at some point.